# TYPO3: indexed_search - index all pages without visiting first

Tags: search, typo3

Normally indexed_search only indexes already visited pages. If a user hasn't visited the page, there are no search results. Is there a way to index all pages without visiting? Or do I have to use another extension?

Typo3: v. 4.2.8
Indexed_search: v. 2.11.1

Comment: You're a bit daring, aren't you? TYPO3 4.2 is completely out of support (including security updates) since ages! See http://news.typo3.org/news/article/end-of-life-for-typo3-42/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [crawler](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/crawler/current/) extension.

Answer (score 0):

StephenKing's answer would be the preferred solution. Less sophisticated method is setting **[Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)** to call **[Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget)** to crawl pages in a defined interval:

```
0 * * * *  wget -nv -nc -nd -np -r -l0 -P/var/tmp/ -erobots=off --accept=htm,html,php --wait=1 --delete-after http://www.example.com/ >/dev/null 2>&1
```